# My app dont recognize a this.props action as a function (React - Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Dont recognize my action as a function.

Hello, im setting up a React-Redux application, and i want to centralize the all the set.states of my projects in one unique store.First, i was trying to call an actios that gives me data of an external API (In array form), it worked well in react, and it worked well too in a friends project.
The compiler keeps telling me that the action call method is not a function.
Thanks

Here's the problematic function:

```
 /*imports*/
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { getPokeList } from '../../actions/pokeList';



  componentDidMount = () => {
    const pokeUrl = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`;
    getPokeInfo(pokeUrl)
      .then(data => this.props.getPokeList(data.results)) <---
  }

 /* connection */
 const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pokeList: state.pokeList.elements,
 });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getPokeList })(List);
```

Heres my action method:

```
const GET_LIST = 'GET_LIST';
export default {
GET_LIST,
}
export const getPokeList = list => ({ type: GET_LIST, list });
```

And here's my reducer:

```
import pokeList from '../../actions/pokeList'

const initialState = {
  list: [],
 };

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if (action.type !== null) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case pokeList.GET_LIST:
        return { ...state, list: action.list };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

For the moment i dont use the result data in any part of my code.
Thanks and excuse my english!

Comment: Please add code of your whole component.
Did you `connect` it properly?

Comment: I just added the connection and the import part, thsnks for reading btw

Comment: @NachoCebey: Please share the code for `getPokeInfo`

Comment: Just before you call it, have you tried `console.log(this.props.getPokeList)` to see what it actually is?

Comment: put `console.log(getPokeList)` somewhere out your component to see if its imported correctly.

Comment: It returns undefined

Comment: I have a Git repo if you want to check it up (https://github.com/nachocebey/ReduxTry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.jsx you need to change the Link import to:

```
import List from '../../components/List/List';
```

After this your reducers will be reached, etc. I made it this far after pulling down your code. I wasn't sure what you were trying to achieve after this, so I left it at that.

Ultimately, the issue you encountered is because you have "export default" in your Link component.

Comment: 4 hours for two curly braces man.Reeeeally thank you so mutch (And thanks for wasting your time reading on my git)